# An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Someone can help me with this error on composer update

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>
> > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> >     Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs..\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry.php
>   on line 50 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting
>   ';' or '{' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs..\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry.php
>   on line 50 Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when generating the bootstrap
>   file.

Comment: Symfony and php versions?  The very latest version of Doctrine requires php 7.1 http://www.doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html You may need to tweak the composer.json file.

Comment: Tks for answer. You are right. I upgraded PHP to 7.1 and the error is gone.